# jquery .on is not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a listview with many rows, when the user click on any row, I load data about that row and put the result in another div.

This dynamic content have this code:

```
<div id="reasondiv">
                    <div style="float: left;padding-left:10px;  margin-left:134px;">
                        <label style="color: red; padding-right: 3px;">*</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="callDispoSelect" ClientIDMode="Static">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Reason</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Change of Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Cancellation</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Wait List</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        <input runat="server" id="visitID" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                        <label id="importantSign" style="color: red; padding-right: 3px">*</label>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#callDispoSelect', function () {
    var selectedValue = $("#callDispoSelect").val();
    if ((selectedValue == 1) || (selectedValue == 5)) {
        $("#visitID").show();
        $("#importantSign").show();
        $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
    } else {
        if (selectedValue == -1) {
            $("#visitID").hide();
            $("#importantSign").hide();
            $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
        } else {
            $("#visitID").hide();
            $("#importantSign").hide();
            $("#saveandclosebutton").show();
        }
    }
});
```

I got `undifined is not a function` in the `on`

I read a lot through google and I found that I have to use `$(document)` and that is what I did. but that didn't help me

#### I can see the IDs is not changing. I see that from Google F12 and Firebug, so the IDs is not changing

#### note

I am loading the dynamic content using this:

```
$('#subView').load('SubView.aspx');
```

Please help

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It may be complaining about the `$()` rather than the `on` if the error is not specific? Is you jQuery code wrapped in a jQuery load event?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie jquery 1.4, but I can use any version you suggest

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie my jquery code is in the document.ready and inside that document.ready i have code to hide some divs and that code is working.

Comment: Argh... Move to 1.8.1 or later. 1.4 does not have `on`. It was added in 1.7 :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie please wait, I will do that and update you

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie is this jquery good? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: That is the latest non-HTML-5-only version, so yes. I recommend it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you are my God, it works, please write an answer and I will upvote you and I will call all my friends to upvote to you, you are the God

Comment: Do you trigger the `change` event with `$(document).trigger( "change" );`  ?

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: Ali Naci Erdem deserves the credit (answer below). If you want to check out my other top-voted answers feel free to browse :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are using a decent version of jQuery? When I come accross such a problem its almost always an old version issue.

From http://api.jquery.com/on/ ;

"version added: 1.7"

Comment: yes I am sure I am using jquyer libarary, I have many code and the other code is working

Comment: +1: Well guessed. I would not have expected anyone to still be using jQuery 1.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {
        $('#callDispoSelect').on('change', function () {
            var selectedValue = $('#callDispoSelect').val();
        if ((selectedValue == 1) || (selectedValue == 5)) {
            $("#visitID").show();
            $("#importantSign").show();
            $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
        } else {
            if (selectedValue == -1) {
                $("#visitID").hide();
                $("#importantSign").hide();
                $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
            } else {
                $("#visitID").hide();
                $("#importantSign").hide();
                $("#saveandclosebutton").show();
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: No, it is recommended we use `on` instead of `live`. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I need anything works please. Also, where should I put that? in the script in the main page or in a script inside the subview.asp ?

Comment: live is depreciated in the newer version of jquery. "on" is the way to go.

Comment: Put script at the end of the page.

Comment: The point of `$(function(){})` document load is that is can go anywhere after jQuery is included. It does not have to go at the end of the page.

Comment: For fast serving of the content always put non required thing at the end of the page.

Comment: This tiny script will have no impact on page load, but if you insist, put it last :) The asker was using jQuery 1.4, and wrapped in load event, so this is not the answer anyway :)

Comment: If only the asker was using *your system* :) (That's because their only problem was using jQuery 1.4 and you were not). Your code is actually no different to theirs. They just did not show it all.